# EditText's setError() crashes

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to use `setError()` method on `EditText`, but everytime it crashes with this log:

```
 12-14 17:07:30.764    2026-2026/com.facta.msmart E/PropertyValuesHolder﹕ Couldn't find no-arg method for property currentBottomLines: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getCurrentBottomLines [] 12-14 17:07:30.765    2026-2026/com.facta.msmart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.facta.msmart, PID: 2026
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.setupSetterAndGetter(PropertyValuesHolder.java:533)
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator.initAnimation(ObjectAnimator.java:410)
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:538)
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:928)
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:951)
            at com.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:385)
            at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText.adjustBottomLines(MaterialEditText.java:827)
            at com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText.onLayout(MaterialEditText.java:803)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1692)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1468)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1502)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1626)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
```

I'm calling setError normally inside a fragment, like this:

```
mEditText.setError("test")
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you sure that the `mEditText` is initialized?

Comment: Some more code where you are actually doing this?

Answer (score -1):

I was using MaterialEditText's library to reproduce the Floating Label property of Lollipop in KitKat.. because some months ago AppCompat still didn't have make this work.. This problem was occurring just when I tried to setError on MaterialEditText. I updated AppCompat to the newest version + TextInputLayout + Android's EditText and I got everything working right: the setError method and the Floating Label in both KitKat and Lollipop.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the issue you outlined above, though.